# Sony Vegas: Preview Device in Preferences does not list my NVIDIA card only Windows Graphics Card?

Tags: nvidia-geforce, sony-vegas

I am unable to select my NVIDIA card (GTX 675) in the Preview Device settings, only the Windows graphics card, and preview performance is terrible.  I am unable to preview a simple blur text effect on top of a video stream. The CPU ventillators go through the roof, and the preview skips almost the entire scene.
**I can select NVIDIA card for the video processing settings (GPU).**
Is there anything I Can do?